# Getting error on building angular app "This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular version 5.0.0 or higher"

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I am building my angular app using **ng build** command.
But I am getting error --
*This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular version 5.0.0 or higher.
Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/*.

I have attached output of **ng -v** command when run on my project here--- [[image: output of ng -v]

Comment: try `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: you need upgrade your global angular version to 5+ as cli 6.1x is compatible with Angular 5x or above only

Comment: your current global installed version of Angular is 2.4.x

Comment: Thanks Niladri. Problem was due to older global Angular version. I tried "npm install -g @angular/core@latest" and then solved rxjs compatibility to get it running. 
"npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer my question, as I am able to solve it with the help of comments on my post.

The error - *“This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular version 5.0.0 or higher”*, comes when Angular version is older than Angular CLI and is not compatible with it.

**To solve this, update your global Angular Core version by using below npm command**

```
npm install -g @angular/core@latest
```

After executing this command, you may also get some errors with rxjs node_module. To solve compatibility issues with newer Angular version and rxjs module execute below npm command.

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: Angular CLI version is up to date, instead I had to update @angular/core for solving this issue. Please check my answer to the question.